# override second matched regex with first matched regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to override the second matched egex with first matched regex but my code sees the second matched egex and deletes the first (not memorizing).

**Ex:** If I type "baslamak", it prints "basLMak" and deletes the "a" which should be...target string *(what I want)*: basLamak

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
  
var text2 = $(this).val();
  
 text2 = text2.replace(/l(?=a)/g, "L");
 text2 = text2.replace(/am/g, "M");
     
$("#ta_1").val(text2);
  
});
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
  
 <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: There isn't `M` In your expected result, So what is `text2.replace(/am/g, "M");` in your code?

Comment: @Shafizadeh if the code sees "La" before i don't want "M" :/

Comment: From what i understand probably if you make the second one like `/[^L](am)/g` and do `text2.replace(/[^L](am)/g, (m,n1) => (n1=="am" && "M") );` should be fine.

Comment: @Redu yes exactly but i also want "M"  ex: if a type "bam" it should print "bM" ,, "am"  ->"M" ,,,, "kam"  ->"kM"  etc etc :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex:

```
([^L]|^)am
```

... and keep the captured group in the replacement:

```
$1M
```

So your code would become:

```js
$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
    var text2 = $(this).val();
    text2 = text2.replace(/l(?=a)/g, 'L');
    text2 = text2.replace(/([^L]|^)am/g, '$1M');
    $("#ta_1").val(text2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ta_1" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is ok

```
text2.replace(/([^L]|\b)(am)/g, (m,n1,n2) => (n2=="am" && n1 +"M"));
```

though there might be an easier way.

Comment: yes sir but i also want "M" ex: if a type "bam" it should print "bM" ,, "am" ->"M" ,,,, "kam" ->"kM"  :/ not working in case "bam" "kam" "am" etc etc

Comment: i guess it does so